# Как работает защита покер-румов?

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, защита

Может кто нибудь знает, по какому принципу защита работает (алгоритм) известных покер-румов?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42113/discussion-on-question-by-bigman-----).